# Library module is not updated in the project after gradle sync

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-library

I have a library project and when I make changes to the library project, I rebuild it in order for those changes to take effect. To do this, I went to the "Build" menu in Android Studio and select "Rebuild Project" for the library project.

After I rebuilt the library project, I synced my new project with Gradle which includes this library project as a module in order to pull in the changes.I did Sync Now in build.gradle.

After those above steps, I was still not able to get the changes made inside the library project into my new android project.

I have implemented my library project as below inside app level `build.gradle` file.

> implementation project(':ecg')

Also inside `settings.gradle` i have done the below:

> include ':ecg'

What am i missing here?